# Converting an image to grayscale using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

I have an image represented by a [`numpy.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) matrix *nxm* of triples `(r,g,b)` and I want to convert it into grayscale, , using my own function.

My attempts fail converting the matrix *nxmx3* to a matrix of single values *nxm*, meaning that starting from an array `[r,g,b]` I get `[gray, gray, gray]` but I need `gray`.

i.e. Initial colour channel : `[150 246 98]`.
     After converting to gray : `[134 134 134]`.
     What I need :  `134`

How can I achieve that?

**My code:**

```
def grayConversion(image):
    height, width, channel = image.shape
    for i in range(0, height):
        for j in range(0, width):
            blueComponent = image[i][j][0]
            greenComponent = image[i][j][1]
            redComponent = image[i][j][2]
            grayValue = 0.07 * blueComponent + 0.72 * greenComponent + 0.21 * redComponent
            image[i][j] = grayValue
    cv2.imshow("GrayScale",image)
    return image
```

Comment: please use vectorization instead of nested for loops.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? @Quickbeam2k1

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your quetion right. What's exactly the problem with the opencv conversion? Do you want to implement the opencv conversion yourself?

Comment: There is no any problem with opencv conversion. 
Yes, I wanted a 2-dimensional array of image implementing my own code.

Comment: [thesamiroli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8804904/thesamiroli) if my answer isn't correct could you please expand on what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Sure.  am implementing what you provided. @LucaCappelletti

Comment: If my answer solves your question consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: please check my comment on your answer @LucaCappelletti

Comment: I have extended the answer including a textual example, hoping it can clear doubts on the input and output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working code:

```
def grayConversion(image):
    grayValue = 0.07 * image[:,:,2] + 0.72 * image[:,:,1] + 0.21 * image[:,:,0]
    gray_img = grayValue.astype(np.uint8)
    return gray_img

orig = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Jackson\Desktop\drum.png', 1)
g = grayConversion(orig)

cv2.imshow("Original", orig)
cv2.imshow("GrayScale", g)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2):

### Solution using `apply_along_axis`

A solution can be achieved by using [`apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html):

```
import numpy as np
def grayscale(colors):
    """Return grayscale of given color."""
    r, g, b = colors
    return 0.21 * r + 0.72 * g + 0.07 * b

image = np.random.uniform(255, size=(10,10,3))
result = np.apply_along_axis(grayscale, 2, image)
```

### Examples

#### 10x10 image

We can now proceed to visualise the results:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(result, cmap='gray')
```

[image: Example results]

#### Textual example (2x2 image)

To visualise the actual results in text I will use a smaller array, just a *2x2* image:

```
image = np.random.uniform(250, size=(2,2,3))
```

The content is:

```
array([[[205.02229826, 109.56089703, 163.74868594],
    [ 11.13557763, 160.98463727, 195.0294515 ]],

   [[218.15273335,  84.94373737, 197.70228018],
    [ 75.8992683 , 224.49258788, 146.74468294]]])
```

Let's convert it to grayscale, using our custom function:

```
result = np.apply_along_axis(grayscale, 2, image)
```

And the output of the conversion is:

```
array([[127.62263079, 157.64461409],
   [117.94766108, 197.76399547]])
```

We can visualise this simple example too, using the same code as above:

[image: Smaller example]

### Further suggestions

If you want to apply your own custom function, then `apply_along_axis` is the way to go, but you should consider using *purer numpy approaches* such as the one suggested by [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102441/eric) or, if possible, just load the black and white image using `cv2` option:

```
cv2.imread('smalltext.jpg',0)
```

Comment: so, the result variable should be a grayscale image right ? or am i missing something because when I try to display it, it only shows white pixels everywhere.

Comment: Yes, but he asked for using his own custom function.

Comment: [Your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51285593/converting-an-image-to-grayscale-using-numpy/51286918#comment89549633_51285593) gives the misleading impression that this is better because it avoids a python loop - but a python loop is exactly what apply_along_axis does.

Comment: [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102441/eric) Comment removed, you are right.

Comment: @thesamiroli I believe so. What does it happen when using the cv2 grayscale loading `cv2.imread('smalltext.jpg',0)`?

Comment: @LucaCappelletti This is not the point of the question. The OP wants to use numpy to convert an image to grayscale.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dot product:

```
gray_image = image.dot([0.07, 0.72, 0.21])
```

Or even just do the whole operation manually:

```
b = image[..., 0]
g = image[..., 1]
r = image[..., 2]
gray_image = 0.21 * r + 0.72 * g + 0.07 * b
```

Don't forget to convert back to 0-255:

```
gray_image = np.min(gray_image, 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: The image is still a 3-dimensional array.

Comment: You mean `gray_image.ndim == 3`? It's 2 on my machine